# If $S=\{(1,0,i),(1,2,1)\}\subseteq X^3 $ then $S^{\bot}$ is span$\{(i,-\frac{1}{2}(1+i),1)\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthogonality

> If $S=\{(1,0,i),(1,2,1)\}\subseteq X^3 $ then $S^{\bot}$ is span$\{(i,-\frac{1}{2}(1+i),1)\}$.

This gives me 2 equations: $x+iz=0$ and $x+2y+z=0$ which gives me the general element of $S ^\bot$ as $z\left(-i,\frac{i-1}{2},1\right )$ but the given answer is  span$\{(i,-\frac{1}{2}(1+i),1)\}$ and I'm not able to show that they are equivalent.

Comment: What does $X$ signify? Do you mean $\Bbb C$, the field of complex numbers?

Comment: This was an MCQ and I have exactly copied the entire question. I would guess $X$ is $\mathbb C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard dot product of two complex vectors $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ is in fact not $x_1x_2+y_1y_2 + z_1z_2$, but rather
$$
\overline{x_1}x_2+\overline{y_1}y_2 + \overline{z_1}z_2
$$
This is necessary to ensure that, for instance, the dot product of any vector with itself is a real (and non-negative) number.

Using this will give you slightly different equations, and presumably you get the given solution when you solve those.

Comment: This new definition fixes the problem. Is this the default dot product when dealing with complex vectors? I thought it would be mentioned explicitly in the question if they want us to use this altered dot product.

Comment: @Rhaldryn Yes, it is the default when dealing with complex vectors. As mentioned, using the unaltered dot product you know from real numbers doesn't allow the dot product of a vector with itself to be a non-negative real number. Which is usually considered a very good thing to have. There are other, more subtle properties too that differentiate them, and with respect to the vast majority, the conjugating variation is better behaved.